# Extract the variables and values from an ajax text response

Tags: arrays, ajax, text

The result I get from an AJAX function is a text with this format :

```
"&userId=2&mytotal=7&name0=this+is+my+text&name0=this+is+another+text&name1=this+is+a+third+text"

How can I get the different variables and values with this format ?

userId=2
mytotal=7
name[0]="this is my text"
name[1]="this is another text"
name[2]="this is a third text"

Thank you for your help.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "&userId=2&mytotal=7&name0=this+is+my+text&name0=this+is+another+text&name1=this+is+a+third+text";
data = text.split("&");

var myValues = {};
for(var d in data){
    var parts = data[d].split("=");
    if(parts[0] != ""){
        if(parts[0].match(/[\w]+(\d)/)){
           var mt = parts[0].match(/[\w]+(\d)/); 
           var prop = mt[0].replace(mt[1],"");
           if(!myValues.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
              myValues[prop] = [];
              myValues[prop].push(parts[1]);
           }else{
              myValues[prop].push(parts[1]);
           }

       }else{
          myValues[parts[0]] = parts[1];  
       }

    }
}
console.log(myValues);
//Object { userId: "2", mytotal: "7", name: Array[3] }
```